# I want my customers to fill in their address and this address to show on my Google maps. How do I approach this?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, web-applications

I'm building a website where I want to create the option that when registerd customers login for the first time they have to fill in their address, this address then gets put in my Google maps along side the others. So when visitors see my maps they can see all my customers geographically and click on them.

I'm building my site with PHP& mysql.

Comment: We will not write your website for you.  Please ask a **specific** question.  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @markus thats my problem where do i start? I've seen some tutorials. But i do not no where to start with my specific need.

Comment: @jan: Start by dividing the problem into smaller parts; continue by dividing those into smaller parts, and so on, until you get to tiny problems that can be directly translated to code.

Comment: What have you done with PHP so far?

Comment: @markus as i mentioned to Piskovar below. The php part has already been done. The address's of the customers are stored in DB. I need the adresses's appear in my googleMaps.

Comment: So obviously you need to use the Google API, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At login:

```
Has customer logged in before?
 If not:
   Get address from customer
   Geolocate coordinates from address
   Insert coordinates into database
```

In map:

```
Get all customers' coordinates, if they have been entered
Add each as a marker
```

Comment: yeah i have already done the php side of that and the address list of the customers already exist in my DB. I need all of these address's to appear in my google maps?

Comment: @jan: Do you? I don't know, you tell me.

Comment: @jan: Anyway, you need to `SELECT` the coordinates from whatever table you put them into, and then add them to the map, probably using a MarkerManager: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Marker_Manager